# concat operator evaluates requests' payloads before executing them

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm working on an Angular app (Angular 16.2.0, RxJS 7.8.0).
I have 3 HTTP requests I need to execute in a specific order. I looked at the official RxJS website and decided to go with concat.

I put my 3 requests as parameters of the concat operator and started the app.
I noticed that the payload was evaluated right at the beginning, even before the HTTP calls were really executed. It was not OK with me because I needed some information from the second request to be added to the third one. I thought the payload of each request would be evaluated only when the request was sent to the backend, but no.

Here's what I tried.
When the ExecuteRequests method is called, all 3 payloads are evaluated and never updated.
Is there a way to update payload3 before the HTTP call is done?

```
    url1: string;
    url2: string;
    url3: string;

    payload1 = { id: null };
    payload2 = { id: null };
    payload3 = { id: null, fullname: null };

    ExecuteRequests() {
        concat(this.Request1(), this.Request2(), this.Request3()).subscribe();
    }

    Request1() {
        return this.http.post(this.url1, this.payload1);
    }

    Request2() {
        return this.http.post(this.url2, this.payload2)
            .pipe(map((data: any) => {
                this.payload3.fullname = data.fullname;
            }));
    }

    Request3() {
        // Here, this.payload3.fullname is always null and doesn't get the update from Request2
        return this.http.post(this.url3, this.payload3);
    }
```

Comment: This isn't an Angular/RxJS problem, just basic JS control flow. You call all three functions _at the same time_ and pass their return values, the observables, to concat.

Comment: I didn't think of it this way. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better solution for this is to use the `switchMap` operator. This way you can map an observable to another observable. Something like this:

```
ExecuteRequests() {
  this.Request1().pipe(
    switchMap(response => this.Request2()),
    switchMap(response => this.Request3(response.fullname))
  );
}

Request3(fullname: string) {
  return this.http.post(this.url3, {
    fullname: fullname,
    ...
  });
}
```

Comment: I agree with you that it's a better solution. I've used switchMap in other situations but with only 2 requests, switching from the first one to the second and done.
But, here, we have the same mecanism, with one more request.
And also, i don't really use and get advantage of the concat mecanism, meaning i don't care if the final result is the concatenation of the inner observables.
So, yeah, switchMap it is. And it's working just fine.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To delay the evaluation untill subscription happends use `defer` operator

```
concat(this.Request1(), defer(() => this.Request2()), defer(() => this.Request3())).subscribe();
```

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot.
I'll remember of this defer operator for other situations.
Thanks again.